# Best Way to Split Lines

Tags: json, format, sublimetext3

I have long query text i want to Send it Application via an API so my body look like this:

```
"query" : "select * from table"
```

But for very long query which are spread over multiple line how to format my text ?

Example :

```
WITH temp1 AS (
SELECT *,
  CAST(STORE AS STRING) as store_number,
  TRIM(TIME) AS timezone_code
FROM TABLE
WHERE CNTRY = 'US'
// other text
),
// other temp tables
Select temp1.a , temp2.b from temp1, temp2
```

How to format this ?

Answer (score 0):

To join multiple lines into one, select them all, then select **`Edit → Line → Join Lines`**. You can then surround them with double quotes and put the whole query into your JSON.